# How to draw on an ImageView

Tags: android

Why will this code not draw a circle where the user touches in an imageview and output the coordinates to a textview?

```
package com.smallbore.smallbore;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class targetenter extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.targetenter);
    }

   public class ImageView1 extends ImageView {
        public int x;
        public int y;
        public ImageView1(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
        public boolean dispatchtouchevent(MotionEvent event){
            x = (int) event.getX();
            y = (int) event.getY();
            TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            t1.setText("x="+x);
            TextView t2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            t2.setText("y="+y);
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.drawCircle(x,y,10, null );
    }
}
}
```

and the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/cposition" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <com.smallbore.smallbore.targetenter.Imageview1 android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_width="300dip" android:layout_height="300dip" android:background="@drawable/target" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"></com.smallbore.smallbore.targetenter.Imageview1>
    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `onTouchEvent` to [`dispatchTouchEvent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#dispatchTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29). Also, make sure that you are using `imageView1` in your XML, and not just `ImageView`.

Comment: so I would need:        <ImageView1 android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_width="300dip" android:layout_height="300dip" android:background="@drawable/target" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"></ImageView1> ?

Comment: its okay, sorted that part now, I think

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling invalidate() in your onTouchEvent. When ever you change something on a canvas it must be redrawn. fyi, if you are not on UI thread you must call postinvalidate(). refer to this api demo to learn more about dealing with drawing on canvas. http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that Cristian's suggestion of using `dispatchTouchEvent()` is a good one, that method makes sense in `ViewGroup` descendants to *dispatch* touch events to its children. Yet his recommendation of using the custom view in xml layout declaration is important. You do that like:

```
<package.that.contains.targetenter.imageView1 android:id ....
```

that is, you need to specify the full package to your custom `ImageView` class (btw, in Java there's the convention of using capital letter for class names: `imageView1 -> ImageView1`). You simply have to use it were you were using `ImageView`, and I think you will have to make it public or better declare it in another file.

To have your `onDraw()` method called, you'll need to call `invalidate()` as Veeresh suggests, so that your imageView1 will redraw. But you have to call its super, or you will only get the circles drawn:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawCircle(x,y,10, null );
}
```

If you're still having problems it might be useful to see your `targetenter.xml` layout.

Comment: And how do I make the class public/declare it in another file? sorry, I'm quite new to this.

Comment: @Leo: well right now you are declaring it as a nested class in your activity, and it's not declared public, so I'm not sure Android will find it when loading your layout. I think just adding "public" should do the job. If it doesn't work you can just cut and paste class ImageView1 in another file called ImageView1.java and update the package path in xml.

Comment: I'm getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException I assume this means that the XML isn't pointing to the class in the right way, but I've tried what is above, and I've putting it into com.smallbore.smallbore ImageView1.java containing the class ImageView1 and then pointin the xml as above to com.smallbore.smallbore.ImageView1.ImageView1 but that doesn't work either.

Comment: @Leo: you're doing all right but `com.smallbore.smallbore.ImageView1.ImageView1` should be `com.smallbore.smallbore.ImageView1`